# Error using custom comparator class

Tags: java, priority-queue, dijkstra

I am trying to implement Dijkstra's Algorithm for adjaceny matrix, and I am using Java priority Queue to do so.
For my vertex I am creating a custom comparator class, but I am getting the following error:

```
 <anonymous Dijkstra$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(vertex,vertex) in java.util.Comparator
        PriorityQueue<vertex> Q = new PriorityQueue<vertex>(n,new Comparator<vertex>() {
```

here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Comparator;
class vertex {
    int v,d;
    public vertex(int num,int dis){
        v =num;
        d=dis;
    }
    public int getv(){
        return v;
    }
    public int getd(){
        return d;
    }
}
```

and then I use this to create a new priority queue:

```
PriorityQueue<vertex> Q = new PriorityQueue<vertex>(n,new Comparator<vertex>() {        
            public int compare (Object a, Object b){
            vertex v1 = (vertex)a;
            vertex v2 = (vertex)b;
            if (v1.getd() > v2.getd()){
                return +1;
            }else if (v1.getd() < v2.getd()){
                return -1;
            }else {
                return 0;
            }
        }});
```

Comment: if youre using `Comparator<vertex>`, then the compare method signature is: `public int compare (vertex a, vertex b);` moreover, it would be little more elegant to write the compare method as: `return a.getd() - b.getd();`

Comment: `a.getd() - b.getd()` will return incorrect results for very large values, because of overflow.

Comment: @JB Nizet - ofcourse... i'm not always carefull, but a good practice would be to divide by 2 when dealing with large numbers: `return a.getd()/2 - b.getd()/2;` or using classes such as `BigInteger`

Comment: And you would then have two large numbers equal if they differ just by 1. Why not do what the OP does, and which is just fine, or simply use [Integer.compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) or the Guava equivalent if you're in Java 6?

Comment: thanks. this is ofcourse much better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error you are getting is because you did'nt implemented the correct method. the signature of the `compare` method for `Comparator<vertex>` is `public int compare (vertex a, vertex b);` and not `public int compare (Object a, Object b);`.

moreover, as JB Nizer stated wisely, it would be better to implement your compare method as follows:

```
public int compare (vertex a, vertex b) {
    return Integer.compare(a.getd(), b.getd());
}
```